# Can't add socket.io library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I can do anything I can not edit the socket library and make mistakes

```
implementation 'io.socket:engine.io-client:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
```

and error:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve io.socket:engine.io-client:1.0.0. Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   io.socket:engine.io-client:1.0.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   io.socket:engine.io-client:1.0.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app

Comment: where did you put those two lines?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the repository is missing:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
     implementation "io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0"
}
```

see [io.socket](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.socket).

Answer (score 0):

In case you guys are having problems because of jCenter I found an easy way to make my packages keep working. I'm using [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io), with it just add the repository `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` and after that you just put the package address in the github. Example: `implementation 'com.github.ebanx:swipe-button:0.8.3'`

[example for jitpack.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDiJD.png)